# CrateIO insertion failing

Tags: database

Inserting large value in the CrateIO DB. Getting MaxBytesLengthExceededException: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 38044. Tried compressing the entries as gzip and then storing still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/general/ddl/storage.html#ddl-storage-columnstore

Turning off the Column Store in conjunction of turning off indexing worked for me.